# merge two list of elements returned by querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

I want to merge two list of elements returned by document.querySelectorAll

below is what i have tried but it is not good:

```
var ca = document.querySelectorAll(".classA");
    ca = ca + document.querySelectorAll(".classB");
```

I need to merge the list of elements because I need to use just one list in the FOR loop:

```
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) console.log(ca[i].tagName);
```

How to merge two of such lists correctly ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [slice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) to covert a nodelist to an array and [concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) to merge two arrays:

```
var ca = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".classA")).concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".classB")));
```

Answer (score 38):

You can also just do

```
var ca = document.querySelectorAll(".classA, .classB");
```

Comment: "But this requires FF 3.1+, Safari 3.1+, or IE8+" There's no difference in browser support whether you join selectors using commas or use separate calls to `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Actually with joined selectors the output order is the document order of each element whereas 2 merged arrays the order is the items from first array followed by the items from the second array.
The difference is subtle but it is there and can produce different results depending on you usage.